# More efficient way to programatically get a value from a Sharepoint list?

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I am using SharePoint 2010 and get values from a list using the code below.

It might be called like this ...

```
getValueFromList("addresses", "secondName", "city", "manhattan");
```

It will return the "secondName" of the first entry that has "city = manhattan"

Is there a way to make it more efficient?

```
private string getValueFromList(string theList, string returnColumnName,   string matchColumnName, string valueToMatch)
    {
        try
        {
            SPSite siteh2 = SPContext.Current.Site;

            using (SPWeb oWeb = siteh2.OpenWeb())
            {

                //SPWeb oWeb = SPControl.GetContextSite(Context).OpenWeb();
                SPList oList = oWeb.Lists[theList];

                SPQuery oQuery = new SPQuery();
                oQuery.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='" + matchColumnName + "' />" +
                    "<Value Type='Text'>" + valueToMatch + "</Value></Eq></Where>";

                //oQuery.Query = "<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Username' /><Value Type='Text'>whelanp</Value></Eq></Where></Query>";

                SPListItemCollection results = oList.GetItems(oQuery);

                if (results.Count == 0)
                    return "";

                foreach (SPListItem oListItem in results)
                {
                    return cleanValue(oListItem[returnColumnName].ToString());
                }
                return "";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return "";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It seems that your code currently works, and you are looking to improve it. Generally these questions are too opinionated for this site, but you might find better luck at [CodeReview.SE](//codereview.stackexchange.com/tour). Remember to read [their requirements](//codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as they are a bit more strict than this site.

Comment: Thanks for that. I posted a question there ... http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/140122/best-way-to-get-a-value-from-a-list-in-sharepoint-2010